# Windows Form constructor does not accept arguments

Tags: .net, vb.net, constructor

Why do I get an error while filling the Form values, if the Form object was created with arguments?

The error is:

> Reference to non-shared member needs an object reference.

#### File ParentForm.vb

```
Public Class Maincls
Dim oChildForm as New ChildForm("abc") ' Causes an error, but removing the arguments removes the error
Dim oChildForm as New ChildForm ' Does not throw an error
Public Sub btnok_click
ChildForm.tbXYZ.Text = "abc"    ' Reference to non-shared member needs an object reference
End Sub

End Class
```

#### File ChildForm.vb

```
Public Class ChildForm

    Public Sub New(tempString as String)
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the handler for btnok you are using the class name rather than the name of the instance you have created. This should do it.

```
Public Class Maincls

    Dim oChildForm as New ChildForm("abc") 'Causes Error, but removing the arguments removes the error
    Dim oChildForm as New ChildForm 'Does not thow error

    Public Sub btnok_click
        oChildForm.tbXYZ.Text = "abc"    'Reference to non-shared member needs an object reference
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Why does sending argument (during object creation) make a difference, but not otherwise ?

Comment: @SharatChandra - I suppose it probably has to do with VB's **Default Instance** behavior for forms.  In VB6, you could refer to the form just using the class name and for compatibility, that is also available in VB.Net.

Answer (score 1):

In the button click event, change ChildForm to oChildForm.

Comment: Why does sending argument (during object creation) make a difference, but not otherwise ?

Comment: That's indeed pretty weird behavior. I have no explanation for that myself.

Answer (score 0):

For the constructor your must define a value, for example:

```
Sub New() ' You can use "Overload" if it needs to be shared or no shared
          ' for a non-shared member

End Sub

Public Class ChildForm

    Private valStr As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal str As String)
        Me.valStr = str ' Shared Memeber
    End Sub

    Public Property Text As String
        Get
            Return valStr
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            valStr = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

How to use:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
  Handles Button2.Click

    Dim a As New ChildForm("Contoh")
    MsgBox(a.Text)
End Sub
```

Or:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
  Handles Button2.Click

    Dim a As New ChildForm
    a.Text = "Test"
    MsgBox(a.Text)
End Sub
```